# Pandas Python Count how many times a column contains a list of numbers

Tags: python, pandas

Supposed a dataframe looks like this.

```css
.  Value
0  86248
1  55265
2  52654
3  55568
4  56985
5  56855
6  79623
7  56648
    ...
```

I want to count how many times does the numbers`[0,1,2,3...,100000]` appear in the column `Value` and then table the results.

```js
.  Value 
0  86248    df.loc[df.Value == 0, 'Value'].count()
1  55265    df.loc[df.Value == 1, 'Value'].count()
2  52654    df.loc[df.Value == 2, 'Value'].count()
3  55568    df.loc[df.Value == 3, 'Value'].count()
4  56985    df.loc[df.Value == 4, 'Value'].count()
5  56855    df.loc[df.Value == 5, 'Value'].count()
6  79623    df.loc[df.Value == 6, 'Value'].count()
7  56648    df.loc[df.Value == 7, 'Value'].count()
    ...                       ....
            df.loc[df.Value ==100 000, 'Value'].count()
```

> Expected output

```js
.   Value      Counts          
0     2          0        #Count 0
1     5          0        #Count 1
2     9          1        #Count 2
3     8          2        #Count 3
4     3          0        #Count 4
5     3          1        #Count 5
6     7          0        #Count 6
7     6          1        #Count 7
```

Comment: What is your use case? Or why would you want to do that?

Comment: The `Value` column has lots of random numbers and Im trying to calculate how many of them are `1, or 2 or 4 or 5...` so on. Then use the least appearing number. I cannot directly check  how many times 86248` in the `Value` column because this means i would only be counting numbers that appeared on the dataframe where else I want how many times each and every number between 1 and 100 000 appeared in the dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Series.value_counts()` along with a call to `.reindex` to quickly solve this.

Create sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Value": [10, 8, 1, 2, 3, 10, 10, 10, 1, 1]
})

print(df)
   Value
0     10
1      8
2      1
3      2
4      3
5     10
6     10
7     10
8      1
9      1
```

- Create a value_range which is minimum/maximum values I want counts of. In this case, I want to see how many times a number from 0-10 occurs in my "Value" column.
- We then use `df["Value"].value_counts()` to get a count of the number of occurences of each value in that column.
- lastly we use `reindex(value_range, fill_value=0)` to reorder our output of `value_counts()` to include numbers that were not originally in our "Value" column (e.g. 4, 5, 6, 7, 9), if this is the case it will fill those non-existant numbers with 0 (since they were in our original column 0 times)

```
value_range = range(0, 11) 
out = df["Value"].value_counts().reindex(value_range, fill_value=0)

print(out)
0     0
1     3
2     1
3     1
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     1
9     0
10    4
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is the answer Im looking for

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your requirement is:

For each num in [0,1,2....100000], count the number of times num appears in the column 'value'.

e.g result:
0: appears x times
1: appears x times
....

```
counts_dict = dict

for i in [1,2,.....,100000]:
    #how many rows have this value?
    count = len(df[df.value==i])

    #add this to a dictionary
    counts_dict.update({i:count})
```

You now have a dictionary of each value in [1,2,.....,100000] and how many times they appear. You can view this as a dataframe for simplicity:

```
s = pd.Series(counts_dict, name='counts')
```

Where the index of s is your item, and the value is the counts

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(counts_dict)` returns error `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called! `

Comment: Ah yes, since the dictionary only has one value, thats one column, which pandas says is a series i.e. just 1 column. So do the following:

s = pd.Series(counts_dict, name='counts')
s.index.name = 'item'
s